# Удаление словаря в списке по значению

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список словарей:

```
list = [{'id': 123456, 'name': 'a'}, 
        {'id': 456123, 'name': 'a'}, 
        {'id': 789465, 'name': 'a'}]
```

Нужно из него удалить словарь со значением `'id' = 123456`
Делал так:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(list):
    if list[i]['id'] != 123456:
        del list[i]
```

Но так не получается, так как после удаления `i` становится не актуальной и итерация не срабатывает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Кст, не называйте переменные именами built-in, такими как list :) т.к. это название встроенное и вы не сможете использовать `list`, например `list("1234")` после вашего кода перестанет работать, т.к. обращение будет к переменной `list`

Comment: 1 - никогда не используйте имя `list` для своих переменных. 2 - зачем вы в очередной раз для перебора коллекции используете `enumerate`, ведь в предыдущих ваших вопросам вам уже указывали на это. 3 - ваше условие в `if` противоположно тому, что требуется.

Comment: @gil9red, учту это.

Comment: @mkkik, 1) понял, не буду так, 2) я пока так и не разобрался, как без этого делать. 3) Это поменяю) Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что перебор вы делается по возрастающей, но при удалении новые индексы будут неактуальные, т.к. верхняя граница уменьшилась.

Решением будет удаление от конца к началу:

```
items = [
    {'id': 123456, 'name': 'a'},
    {'id': 456123, 'name': 'a'},
    {'id': 789465, 'name': 'a'}
]

for i in reversed(range(len(items))):
    if items[i]['id'] == 123456:
        del items[i]

print(items)
# [{'id': 456123, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 789465, 'name': 'a'}]
```

Тот же цикл, но без `reversed`:

```
for i in range(len(items) - 1, -1, -1):
    if items[i]['id'] == 123456:
        del items[i]
```

Comment: спасибо! Который раз выручаете.

Comment: @danilfg, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше не менять исходный список, а создавать новый:

```
lis1 = [{'id': 123456, 'name': 'a'}, 
        {'id': 456123, 'name': 'a'}, 
        {'id': 789465, 'name': 'a'}]

lst2 = []

for elem in lis1:
    if elem['id'] == 123456:
        lst2.append(elem)

# Или одной строкой:
# lst2 = [elem for elem in lst1 if elem['id'] == 123456]
```

Также добавлю, что не рекомендуется называть переменные именами совпадающими с именами встроенных функций и других объектов (`list`, `set`, `dict` и т.д.)

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

бывает условие слишком сложно для записи в одну стоку, тогда удобно использовать [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), если func вернет True - значение добавится, иначе нет

```
lis1 = [{'id': 123456, 'name': 'a'},
        {'id': 456123, 'name': 'a'},
        {'id': 789465, 'name': 'a'}]

def func(x):
    if x['id'] == 123456:
        return False
    elif x['id'] % 19:
        if x['name'] == 'a':
            return True
        elif x['name'] == 'b':
            return False
    return True

lis1 = list(filter(func, lis1))
```